# Anko layouts - distinguishing layouts in applyRecursively

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

what is the best way to distinguish SOME of the views I want to `applyRecursively {}` something on? E.g. i've got several `textViews`, don't want to create separate containers for them (flat hierarchy!), but still I know some need to have e.g. a particular textSize, some need to have particular colour. Should I generate `ids` in a particular way? For some cases (when some styles are used together) I can of course make up a small function:

```
private fun ViewManager.bigTextView(
    content: String, 
    init: (@AnkoViewDslMarker TextView).() -> Unit) = 
    textView(content) {
        init()
        typeface = medium
        textSize = 16f
    }
```

but what when it's more generic? I was suggested maybe tags would do better.

Comment: why -1? Seriously, I will accept it, but given no explanation I won't learn anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I can suggest is, you can write a set of extension functions for each style you need to apply and then call them while creating your view hierarchy within the DSL. Something like this for `TextView`s:

```
fun TextView.makeBig() {
    typeface = medium
    textSize = 16f
}
```

Then in your DSL:

```
textView(R.string.example) {
    makeBig()
}
```

This approach doesn't require you to generate IDs or set tags, and it looks more or less natural and idiomatic for Kotlin.